# How can I use 'Visual studio shell' in task-scheduler for windows?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-task-scheduler

I compile my code from the visual studio shell(VS shell) using jam. The shell itself is started using "%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86".

I am setting up task-scheduler to do this build every night automatically but the normal shell is being used to for compilation - which fails because it cannot find the compiler and others in the path(this is set automatically within VS shell). I want my jam commands to be run within the 'VS shell' from the task-scheduler. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

I am using the following within a batch script and place the jam command after the following line is executed. This call below is extracted from the vcvarsall.bat file itself.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
```